# Calculate the Laplace transform.

Tags: calculus

Can anybody help me with the answer of this question?

> Find the inverse Laplace transform of  $$f(t)=10$$

Comment: Do you want to *know* the inverse Laplace transform, or do you want to know how to *calculate* the inverse Laplace transform? Because calculating inverse Laplace transforms is in general no easy task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LT of a constant $a$ is

$$\hat{f}(s) = a \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-s t} = \frac{a}{s}$$

Comment: @testan: yes, that is correct.  Please remember to accept a solution that you found useful by clicking on the checkmark on the left.

Comment: The OP claims to want the *inverse* LT

Comment: @mrf: the OP ha confused the LT and ILT in another question here.  It is clear that OP wants the LT.

Answer (score 1):

That would be $10 \times \delta(s)$
About $\delta$ function, see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta
P.S. It is usual that we take Laplace transform on $f(t)$ and we take the inverse Laplace transform on $F(s)$. In your case somehow "t" (perhaps time) is the Laplace variable which is not usual.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!