# Laplace transform of $f(t)=10te ^{-5t}$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

> Find the Laplace transform of  $$f(t)=10te  ^{-5t}$$

Comment: Is this your homework?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421778/calculate-the-laplace-transform

Comment: It is not my homework. I'm studing alone. 
just i need a help.

Comment: Well, Are you sure you want the "inverse" Laplace transform of "f(t)"

Comment: I'm sorry. I revised title and questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$\mathcal{L}(t) = \dfrac{1}{s^2}$$

Thus, we have:

$$\mathcal{L}(10 t e^{-5 t}) = 10 F(s+5) = \dfrac{10}{(s+5)^2}$$

Note: we made use of the Shifting Theorem, which was mentioned to you in another post.

Comment: Thank you ver much. I can understand this type.

Comment: @testan: You are very welcome. It sounds like you are now ready to work on the theory part more to truly get your hands around these transforms. Regards

Comment: Excellent! Nice follow-up, too: encouraging, challenging... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use $$L\{e^{at}f(t)\}=F(s-a) \text{ if } L\{f(t)\}=F(s)$$

and $$L(t^n)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{s^{n+1}}$$ and  $$\Gamma(n+1)=n!\text{ if }n \text{ is non-negative integer}$$

Comment: I'm sorry. I revised title and questions.

Comment: @testan, putting $n=1, L\{t\}=\frac{1!}{s^{1+1}}=\frac1{s^2}$  and consequently, $L\{10t e^{-5t}\}=10\cdot \frac1{(s+5)^2}$