# Laplace Transform of $100e^{-5t}\sin10t$

Tags: calculus, self-learning

Can anybody help me with the answer of this question?

> $$100e^{-5t}\sin10t$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$$\mathcal{L}(\sin 10 t) = \dfrac{10}{s^2 + 100}$$

We have:

$$\mathcal{L}(e^{-5 t} \sin 10 t) = F(s+5) = \dfrac{10}{(s+5)^2 + 100}$$

Lastly, we multiply by $100$, to yield:

$$\mathcal{L}(100e^{-5t}\sin10t) = \dfrac{1000}{(s+5)^2 + 100}$$

Comment: !!! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @testan: You are very welcome. I supposed you learned the shifting theorem from your earlier posts and responses. Regards

Comment: Can I ask one more to you..?
I can't understand this type..
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421793/laplace-transform-of-ft-10te-5t

Comment: @testan: See my answer at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421793/laplace-transform-of-ft-10te-5t/421926#421926

Comment: You accomplished quite a bit on math.se today! +1

Comment: Was this service for your deceased neighbor?

Comment: @amWhy: Yes, he was a nice old guy, really smart and straight shooter, I like people like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first shifting theorem:

$$\mathcal L(e^{-at}f(t))=F(s+a)$$

Where $F(s)$ is the Laplace Transform of f(t) , so knowing that:
 $$\mathcal L( a \sin(wt))= a\mathcal L(\sin(wt))=a\frac{w}{s^2+w^2}$$

$$f(t)=100\sin(10t) \implies F(s)=100*\frac{10}{(s^2+10^2)}$$

$$\mathcal L(e^{-5t}f(t))=\frac{1000}{((s+5)^2+100)}$$

Comment: !!! Thank you for your answer!..
And can you answer this? I don't understand this..
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421793/laplace-transform-of-ft-10te-5t